# @InvocableVariables in Apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method, test-setup, invocablevariable

I am having difficulty writing tests for the apex class. This is my first time working with apex classes and I don't understand how to send  to @InvocableVariable. I've read answers to similar questions, but I still can't solve this problem. Thank you for your help!
Apex class:

```
public class NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource {

// Engine
@InvocableMethod
public static List <Results> execute (List<Requests> requestList) 
{

    List<NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c> inputJourCollection = requestList[0].inputJourCollection;       
    for(NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c OneDay : inputJourCollection)
    {

        NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c[] CurrentJour = [SELECT User_ID__c, Collaborateur__c FROM NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c WHERE Id =: OneDay.Id];

        List<String> caseNouveau = new List<String>();
        Integer nmbrPoints=0;
        integer a=0;
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Points_de_traitement__c FROM Case WHERE OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];
        for(Case caseN : cases)
        {
            a=integer.ValueOf(caseN.Points_de_traitement__c);          
            nmbrPoints=nmbrPoints+a;
            system.Debug(nmbrPoints);
        }
        Integer nmbrCaseNouveau = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE (Status ='Nouveau' OR Status='En cours') AND OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];
        Integer nmbrCaseNiveau5 = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE (Status ='Nouveau' OR Status='En cours') AND Priority ='5 - Critique (Production)' AND OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];
        Integer nmbrCaseNiveau4 = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE (Status ='Nouveau' OR Status='En cours') AND Priority ='4 - Critique' AND OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];
        Integer nmbrCaseSlaOut = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE (Status ='Nouveau' OR Status='En cours') AND (Priority ='3 - Urgente' OR Priority ='2 - Normale' OR Priority ='1 - Basse') AND SLA_Resolution_Out__c = true AND OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];
        Integer nmbrCaseTotal = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE OwnerId =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];

        NWT_NOWRH_RESSOURCE__c myRessource = [SELECT Nouveau_en_cours_Tickets__c, Points_de_traitements_Tickets__c, SLA_Out_Tickets__c, Total_Tickets__c, X4_Critiques_Tickets__c, X5_Critiques_Prod_Tickets__c FROM NWT_NOWRH_RESSOURCE__c WHERE Collaborateur__c =: CurrentJour[0].User_ID__c];

        myRessource.Points_de_traitements_Tickets__c = nmbrPoints; 
        myRessource.Nouveau_en_cours_Tickets__c = nmbrCaseNouveau;
        myRessource.X5_Critiques_Prod_Tickets__c = nmbrCaseNiveau5;
        myRessource.X4_Critiques_Tickets__c = nmbrCaseNiveau4;
        myRessource.SLA_Out_Tickets__c = nmbrCaseSlaOut;
        myRessource.Total_Tickets__c = nmbrCaseTotal;

        update myRessource;

    }
    SObject outputMember = inputJourCollection[0];
    Results response = new Results();
    response.outputMember = outputMember;
    List<Results> responseWrapper= new List<Results>();
    responseWrapper.add(response);
    return responseWrapper;         
}

//Input all flow vars
public class Requests 
{
  @InvocableVariable(required=true)
  public List<SObject> inputJourCollection;
}    
//output all flow vars
public class Results 
{     
  @InvocableVariable
  public SObject outputMember;
}
}
```

Apex test :

```
@isTest
class NWT_Calc_Charge_RessourceTest 
{
        @isTest static void setup() 
        {
            UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'yon', Name = 'yon');
            insert r;
            User u = new User(
                ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id,
                LastName = 'last',
                Email = 'puser001@amamama.com',
                Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                CompanyName = 'TEST',
                Title = 'title',
                Alias = 'alias',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                UserRoleId = r.Id
            );
            insert u;
            User u2 = new User(
                ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id,
                LastName = 'last',
                Email = 'puser002@amamama.com',
                Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                CompanyName = 'TEST',
                Title = 'title',
                Alias = 'alias',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                UserRoleId = r.Id
            );
            insert u2;
            System.runAs(u){
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                acc.ShippingLatitude = 75.46;
                acc.ShippingLongitude = 45.46;
                //acc.AccountStatus__c = 'test';
                insert acc;
            }
            System.runAs(u){
                Contact con = new Contact();
                con.LastName = 'Contact1';
                con.AccountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account'].Id;
                insert con;
            }
            System.runAs(u){
                Case t1 = new Case();
                t1.Subject = 'case1';
                t1.Status = 'En cours';
                t1.Origin = 'Web';
                t1.Priority ='1 - Basse';
                t1.Description = 'descr';
                t1.AccountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account'].Id;
                t1.ContactId = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Contact1'].Id;
                t1.Nature__c = 'Incident';
                t1.Type__c = 'Messagerie';
                t1.Sous_Type__c = 'Authentification';
                insert t1;
            }
            System.runAs(u){
                Case t2 = new Case();
                t2.Subject = 'case2';
                t2.Status = 'En cours';
                t2.Origin = 'Web';
                t2.Priority ='1 - Basse';
                t2.Description = 'descr';
                t2.AccountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account'].Id;
                t2.ContactId = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Contact1'].Id;
                t2.Nature__c = 'Incident';
                t2.Type__c = 'Messagerie';
                t2.Sous_Type__c = 'Authentification';
                insert t2;
            }
                System.runAs(u){
                NWT_NOWRH_RESSOURCE__c res1 = new NWT_NOWRH_RESSOURCE__c();
                res1.Name ='res1';
                Decimal heures = 39;
                res1.Heures_de_travail_Semaine__c = heures;  
                res1.OwnerId =  [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE email = 'puser001@amamama.com'].Id;
                insert res1;
            }
                System.runAs(u){
                NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c nj1 = new NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c();
                Date d = Date.today();
                nj1.Date__c = d;
                nj1.Collaborateur__c = [SELECT Id FROM NWT_NOWRH_RESSOURCE__c WHERE Name = 'res1'].Id;
                insert nj1;
            }



    }  
    @isTest static void callRequest()
    {

        Test.startTest();
        NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c[] Jours = [SELECT User_ID__c, Collaborateur__c FROM NWT_NOWRH_JOUR__c];

        List<NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.Requests> Testingthis = new List<NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.Requests>();
        NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.Requests RequestTest  = new NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.Requests();

        RequestTest.inputJourCollection = Jours;
        Testingthis.add(RequestTest);


        //System.assertEquals(sObject.);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you have requests list, call the method like this: List<Results> resultList = NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.execute(Testingthis);

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper - this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your test class after you have a request list call your Method for its code coverage.

```
List<Results> resultList = NWT_Calc_Charge_Ressource.execute(Testingthis);
```

Assuming **Testingthis** is your request list which you need to pass in your method